# Why do I get the error: ZeroDivisionError: 0.0 cannot be raised to a negative power error when loading deit model from Timm

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, transformer-model

I am trying to make inference on the DeiT small variant from [timm](https://github.com/rwightman/pytorch-image-models/blob/master/timm/models/deit.py).

```
from timm.models import create_model
model = create_model('deit_small_patch16_224', pretrained=True)
```

But I get the error:

```
self.scale = head_dim ** -0.5
ZeroDivisionError: 0.0 cannot be raised to a negative power.
```

However, creating a different model with `model = create_model('deit_tiny_patch16_224', pretrained=True)`, I can make inference successfully and it works pretty fine. I understand this error is as a result of a zero being divided by a non-zero value or when being raised to the power of non-zero. But I don't quite get why this model is flagging an error from timm even before loading any data.

Comment: What do you mean "*works pretty fine*"? It throws the error, doesn't it?

Comment: It doesn't throw an error and i can make inference successfully

Comment: Then where does the error come from? Please post a [mre].

Comment: I think I should just open an issue on their github page. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an error with my version of timm. Upgrading timm: `pip install --upgrade timm` solved the problem.